# Instances vs Classes in RDFS

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, ontology, rdfs

The description of the base classes defined by RDFS in the W3C [reference document](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_classes) states that some classes are instances of one class and a subclass of another (or in some cases an instance and subclass of the same class).  Coming from a more traditional object-oriented background, the concept of classes as instances eludes me and I was wondering if anyone could explain to me the effective difference between a class as an instance and a class as a subclass in RDFS.  Thank you!

Comment: **"Coming from a more traditional object-oriented background, the concept of classes as instances eludes me."**  Plenty of object-oriented programming languages have classes as instances of other classes.  E.g., in Java, `java.lang.String.class` is an instance of `java.lang.Class` (and `java.lang.Class.class` is an instance of `java.lang.Class`, too).   That said, the concept of class in RDF(S) and OWL *is* rather different from the concept of classes in object oriented programming languages.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An RDFS class is defined as the set of its instances. Consider the class of *abstract ideas*. Members – instances – of that set include love, honour, duty, pi, evolution, etc. This view of a class is a mathematical concept, so *the set of abstract ideas* is both an idea and quite abstract, so therefore is itself an instance, or member, of the class *abstract ideas*. More prosaically, if a class is a set of things, then RDFS classes both denote sets of things, and are themselves instances of *the set of all classes*, aka `rdfs:Class`.

I think the practical truth is that it's rare in practical RDFS modelling that you find yourself needing to use the capability of the class being an instance of itself. I would say that it's more a consequence of the mathematical definition of the semantics of RDFS. Similarly, a sub-class of a class is any set which is an improper subset of the set denoted by the super-class, which means that every class is a sub-class of itself. There are good mathematical reasons for making this the case, but it often surprises beginners who look at the sub-classes of a given class as defined by a reasoner, and are confused that the reflexive case is included.